# I can change font size in top bar but not font weight (20.04)

Tags: fonts, gnome-shell, 20.04, top-bar

As explained in the title, I can edit the css file `/usr/share/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` and write:

```
stage {
  font-family: Ubuntu, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But for some reason the `font-weight` specification has no effect, however changing the `font-size` works fine.

Is it something I am missing in specifying the font?